# How to Add Google or Bing Map in Apache Cordova App

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I want to add Google or Bing map in my application built by Cordova 
also i want to add Facebook like box.
How can i do that.

Comment: It's simple as set up a map in web page.

Comment: is iframe tag is supported in apache cordova app..?

Comment: Just go to this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/.you can use this map in your project

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your map on a HTML page Ex: map.html
And load that map page to your div. (It works for me using WinJS).

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.HtmlControl" data-win-options="{uri: './map.html'}"></div>
```

Comment: and how do you load the bing/google api ? as far as I know you can't pull it from cdn as long as you don'y pull it from an iframe/ms-webview ?!

Answer (score 0):

> `<div id="map" style="width:100%; height:500px;"></div>`

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    function initialize() 
    {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        codeAddress();
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    if (navigator.geolocation) 
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        map.setCenter(initialLocation);
        });
    }

});
</script>


// and Include 

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.in/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.googlemap.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
```